# Substacting two fields from different table and update the value in the previous field in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables: Item_detail(P_name, Available) and Customer_detail(P_name,Quantity)

Now I want to subtract 'Quantity' field from 'Available' field and then want to set the subtracted value in 'Available' field. I write this code but its not working

```
update Item_detail  
    set Available=(
        select (A.Available-B.Quantity) as Available 
            from Item_detail as A 
            join (select Quantity from Customer_detail  where P_name='ipod') as B 
            where  A.P_name='ipod') ;
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE Item_detail JOIN Customer_detail USING (P_name)
SET    Item_detail.Available = Item_detail.Available - Customer_detail.Quantity
WHERE  P_name='ipod'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
UPDATE Item_detail A
JOIN (SELECT Quantity FROM Customer_detail  WHERE P_name='ipod') AS B    
SET Available=A.Available-B.Quantity
WHERE A.P_name='ipod';
```